# jq convert an json array to csv

Tags: shell, jq

i try to format a .json file in .csv file
my json file is complex, it mixes arrays and bracket.
i don't success to extract the array values

here is an extract of my json file than i want to format in csv file

```json
{
  "creation_date": "2023/06/16 15:55:09",
  "data": {
    "transactionType": "val",
    "environment": "1",
    "location": {
      "zoneId": 2
    },
    "media": {
      "typeCode": 15,
      "postPaymentEvent": [
        {
          "transactionDate": "2022-12-26T16:50:00+01:00",
          "vehicleType": 1,
          "vehicleId": 1533
        },
        {
          "transactionDate": "2022-12-27T16:31:00+01:00",
          "vehicleType": 1,
          "vehicleId": 1533
        },
        {
          "transactionDate": "2022-12-28T15:50:00+01:00",
          "vehicleType": 1,
          "vehicleId": 1533
        }
      ]
    },
    "deviceConfiguration": [
      {
        "id": "PLATFORM_PAR",
        "version": "2.6"
      },
      {
        "id": "PLATFORM_SOFT",
        "version": "2.6"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "000-0"
}
```

And my jq command, i want to get all the value, with and without array elements. I didn't get nothing when i get the value data.media.postPaymentEvent[0].transactionDate.

```
jq --raw-output '[ "creation_date", "data.transactionType",  "data.location.zoneId", "data.media.typeCode",  "data.media.postPaymentEvent[0].transactionDate",  "id" ] as $h | $h, (. | [getpath($h[] / ".")]) | @csv'
```

Comment: If one implemented a parser to interpret `.name[0]` as the first item in a field called `name`, how would one then address fields actually called `name[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Clever. The easiest way to amend your code to work is to change `[0]` to `.0`, and then match integers and cast them to numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/jq -rn

[
  "creation_date",
  "data.transactionType",
  "data.location.zoneId",
  "data.media.typeCode",
  "data.media.postPaymentEvent.0.transactionDate",
  "id"
] as $h |

$h,
(inputs | ([getpath($h[] |
                    . / "." |
                    map(if test("^[[:digit:]]+$")
                        then tonumber
                        else . end))
           ])) | @csv
```

Comment: when i apply your change, i get a error  : "
          jq: error (at file_PP.json:0): Cannot index array with string "creation_date"
"

Comment: @user4292809, ...sorry 'bout that; apparently failed in retesting after some edits. See current version working @ https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/JaggedWorriedSymbol#main.sh

Comment: and would you have a simple way to get a excel file matching with
"creation_date","data.transactionType", "data..transactionType", "data..environment", "data.location..zoneId", "data.media.typeCode", data..postPaymentEvent.transactionDate", "id"
"2023/06/16 15:55:09","val","1",2,15, "2022-12-26T16:50:00+01:00", 000-0
,,,,, "2022-12-27T16:50:00+01:00",
,,,,, "2022-12-28T16:50:00+01:00",

Comment: If you want to wrap the given jq in shell to do output redirections, I think from the question you already know how to do that. You can put multi-line strings in single quotes in shell so you don't even need to change the formatting.

Comment: i don't simple way to add only the elements of the array on 3 lines, and just have empty elements for the others one

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a new/different question then -- this one covered what you asked for, but it sounds like your real use case is more involved. Generally if you want to do sub-iteration, though, it's time to give up on using the column names as the accessors, and start stuffing values into variables as you iterate down the tree.